# Swift nested type in init function

Tags: swift

I have a nested type object describing some structure:

```
class Car {
   class Electro {
       class 2WheelDrive {
       }
       class 4WheelDrive {
       }
   }
}
```

I want to use that object as a parameter in the init function of another object which signature looks like:

```
init(car: Car)
```

However, when I try to call this init function with `Car.Electro.4WheelDrive` argument, I get an error:

> "cannot convert value of type 'Car.Electro.4WheelDrive' to expected
>   argument type 'Car'".

Which init function signature except `init(car: Any)` should I use to be able to use arguments like `Car.Electro.4WheelDrive`?

Comment: Show actual code fully demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Nesting your classes isn't the same thing as making them subclasses.  You would need to declare it as `class Electro: Car` if you want to pass it to a function that wants a `Car` parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code creates four classes:

- Car
- Car.Electro
- Car.Electro.2WheelDrive (I don't think that's legal; it has to start w/ a letter)
- Car.Electro.4WheelDrive

These are unrelated classes; the only thing they have in common is some namespacing. `Car.Electro` is not a subclass of `Car`. If you want it to be, you need to declare that.

You likely didn't mean to make these nested at all. You probably meant to make them subclasses:

```
class Car {}
class ElectroCar: Car {}
class TwoWheelDriveElectroCar: ElectroCar {}
class FourWheelDriveElectroCar: ElectroCar {}
```

If you want to, you can still nest them of course:

```
class Car {
   class Electro: Car {
       class TwoWheelDrive: Electro {
       }
       class FourWheelDrive: Electro {
       }
   }
}
```

This just changes their names, not their relationships.

Comment: Thanks, Rob, for your answer. Because of a non-related issue in my unit-tests I though that inheritance is not an option for my particular case. But after fixing it, it turned out to be the optimal solution.